# How to compile an application that uses head files from source?

Tags: c++, static, linker, libraries

This question has probally been answered countless numbers of times - there have been simular questions which I've read about but I just still don't understand it.

I have the sources to the libaiml project - a C++ interrepter for aiml a specification for a chatterbox program.

Within the source of the example program, it contains an #include call to a header file :

```
#include "../src/aiml.h"
```

the header file is there, I compiled and linked the program and it states that the header file can't be found.

Various of answers state that the header file needs to be compiled into a static library (a .a file) but how would the program reference the .h file when it's not compiled into the library binary?

Also I tried to compile the srcs into a library with G++ and ar , but it contains alot of errors.
Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: To Just add - the linker doesn't complian that it can't find it - it can , but all the methods that are inside of the library are all undefined.

Comment: If it cant find the header have you provided the include path to your header?

Comment: The relative path looks suspicious. Are you compiling in the correct directory (a sibling directory of `src`)?

Comment: What does this header file contain?? If it contains function definitions rather than function declarations, then you'll need to create one extra module that just includes this file and link it to your program.

Comment: Copy and paste the actual error message.

Comment: The Program is in another folder parallel to the src folder. it is correct , however it brings errors like these : main.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `aiml::cInterpreter::newInterpreter()'

Comment: I'm building it on Debian Linux using the Geany IDE.

Comment: Again, there is no error which states that it can't find the header files? just that it can't find the declarations - however I have the headers files and all the contents seem to be there.

Comment: The sources were designed to be a static library, but they just won't compile correctly - riddled with errors , the same as the one mentioned.

Comment: You should include relevant details in the body of your question.  These would include the command-line(s) that you are using to compile/link, as well as the specific error message that you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I doing anything wrong?

Yes: you completely mis-stated what actually happens to you. You said "it states that the header file can't be found", and "I compiled and linked the program".

But what's really happening is that you've compiled and *failed* to link the program, and the errors have *nothing* to do with the header file; rather you are getting missing symbols at link time.

To fix your problem, you *must* link the `libaiml` *library* to your executable (this library should have been built when you built in the `../src/` directory. Something like this should work:

```
g++ -I../src -o program program.cc -L../src -laiml
```